# Can't attach icon properly

Tags: wpf

The following has been completed:

Using Visual Studio, create Resources dir (place sample.ico in dir) ------ Right click Resources -> Add -> Existing Item -> select sample.ico ------ Right click sample.ico -> Properties -> Advanced -> Resource ------ Add

The icon displays on the dialog box, but the .exe does not display on the desktop.

Comment: Which Visual studio version do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click on your Start up project -> Click on Properties

Replace the default icon by yours.

[image]